# create or update a record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, updating

Im reading from a external db. 
So I have made this so the database get created the first time the code runs.
I only paste the create part. The reading from the external db is code I not allowed to make public.

```
Collection.create(
        name:         xxxxxx,
        title:        xxxxxx,
        description:  xxxxx,
        date:         xxxxx,
        collectie:    xxxxx,
        colors:       xxxxxx,
        small_image:  xxxxxx,
    )
```

How can I change this so the next time only record are updated where data has changed so I do not have to do rake:drop and rake db:migrate and then this rake task if I want to have the latest data.

Edit 1: I tried to change to find_or_create but then I see a lot of errrors

Answer (score 0):

```
item = Collection.where(
    name:         xxxxxx,
    title:        xxxxxx,
    description:  xxxxx,
    date:         xxxxx,
    collectie:    xxxxx,
    colors:       xxxxxx,
    small_image:  xxxxxx
).first_or_create
```

Then you can manipulate item with item.update if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but see then this error message ;   https://gist.github.com/rwobben/1f8c375662bdfb13e1cc4655b17b3e43

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with your model.  Does the collection match the columns in the database?